# I am trying to console log a string and some data from json

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, usda-fooddata-central-api

The strings that I want to printed in the console earlier than the json data.
I am now working with the food data central API

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const params = {
    api_key: '<api_key>',
    query: 'chicken breast raw',
    dataType: ["Survey (FNDDS)"],
    pagesize: 5,
}

const api_url = `https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=${encodeURIComponent(params.api_key)}&query=${encodeURIComponent(params.query)}&dataType=${encodeURIComponent(params.dataType)}&pageSize=${encodeURIComponent(params.pagesize)}`

function getData(){
    return fetch(api_url).then(response => response.json())
}

console.log("Protein:")
getData().then(data=> console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[0].value))

console.log("Fats:")
getData().then(data=> console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[1].value))

console.log("Carbs:")
getData().then(data=> console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[2].value))
```

Output:
`Protein: Fats: Carbs: 8.8 0 26.2`

I just want to print first the string "protein" after the protein value from the json and so on

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what your expected result is and what you are currently getting?

Comment: Instead of the output : Protein: Fats: Carbs: 8.8 0 26.2  I am trying to get: Protein: 26.2(the value of protein) Fats: 8.8(the value of fats) Carbs:0 (the value of carbs)

Comment: You'll probably want to get a new API key since you made this one public.

Comment: hahaha yeah, newbie here i dont know much about api

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Promise`s, which are asynchronously-executing code. This means that things might not necessarily execute in the laid-out order. For example, `fetch` makes a web request and then immediately executes any following code, only executing `then` once data has been returned from the external host.

You could add the logging *inside* the `promise` callback (instead of outside as you currently have it)

```
getData().then(data=> {
    console.log("Protein: ");
    console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[0].value);
})

getData().then(data=> {
    console.log("Fats: ");
    console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[1].value);
});

getData().then(data=> {
    console.log("Carbs: ");
    console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[2].value);
});
```

However, in this situation, I think it's even simpler than that. Every time we call `getData()` it makes a new request *even though we're loading the same data*, so it may make sense to do the request once and then log everything?

```
getData().then(data => {
    const foods = data.foods[0];
    console.log("Protein: ");
    console.log(foods.foodNutrients[0].value);

    console.log("Fats: ");
    console.log(foods.foodNutrients[1].value);

    console.log("Carbs: ");
    console.log(foods.foodNutrients[2].value);
});
```

Or, using a map to make adding new food groups a little easier?

```
const foods = {
  0: 'Protein',
  1: 'Fats',
  2: 'Carbs'
};

getData().then(data => {
  Object.keys(foods).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`${foods[key]}: `);
    console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[key].value);
  });
});
```

Comment: I implement your answer my friend but know I know get any data from the API. Instead I get an time out error: FetchError: request to <link> failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2600:1f12:18a:7d00:217:68d:2c2:3718:443

Comment: @FlorianDima that sounds like there is an issue with the URL you are specifying for your `fetch` command (well, either that or your network connection). If you type the URL out into the browser are you able to access the site normally?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `await`?
e.g.

```
function getData(){
    return fetch(api_url).then(response => response.json())
}

console.log("Protein:")
await getData().then(data=> console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[0].value))

console.log("Fats:")
await getData().then(data=> console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[1].value))

console.log("Carbs:")
await getData().then(data=> console.log(data.foods[0].foodNutrients[2].value))
```

Comment: I get an error : SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Node has had top-level await since v14.8, and `fetch` since v18 (so you don't necessarily need `node-fetch` either.

Comment: You mention await but don't use await at all. Is this an error? @Roshann